# Select specific entities to be tagged

Tags: spacy

Is it possible to only have NER tag a subset on entities. For example I may only need the date and money entities how could I accomplish that?

I’ve looked through the EntityRecognized documentation but didn’t see anything around removing entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it might be possible to accomplish this by retraining the NER tagger. (If you're interested in this route, check out [this article](https://support.prodi.gy/t/only-enable-some-labels-in-spacy-ner-model/1223) that discusses your problem.)

But are you absolutely sure it's necessary though?

For instance, you could create a method that filters the results so that it only returns the entity types you are looking for.

```py
def get_entities(doc):
    for entity in doc.ents:
        if entity.label_ in ["DATE","MONEY"]:
            yield entity
        else:
            continue
```

Then instead of iterating over `doc.ents`, you can iterate over `get_entities(doc)` instead.

This seems like the easier way to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The linked article really helped to clarify things. I was thinking that removing entities would help accuracy for the remaining ones but that is not the case with a pre-trained model.